# Методы блокировки торрент трафика (WireGuard VPN)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, iptables, wireguard

У меня есть WireGuard VPN сервер на Ubuntu 20.04, который я предоставляю для использования другим людям для обхода блокировок. Возник вопрос о том, как реализовать возможность запрета скачивания торрент файлов через мой VPN. При поисках возможных решений нашел следующие правила iptables:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string "BitTorrent" -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string "BitTorrent protocol" -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string "peer_id=" -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string ".torrent" -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string "announce.php?passkey=" -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string "torrent" -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string "announce" -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string "info_hash" -j DROP
```

Такой метод у меня в принципе работает, пользователи VPN действительно не могут скачать нужный им файл с торрент клиента. Но такой метод так же блокирует сайты, которые содержат в себе слова-фильтры в своих доменных именах, что запрещает посещение таких сайтов для пользователей.

**Какие есть возможные варианты для блокировки возможности скачивания торрент файлов для конечных пользователей без блокировки самих сайтов, которые в своей ссылке имеют фильтрационные слова?**

Comment: Единственный правильный вариант - не доверять людям. Отобрать у них доступ к VPN, если они не могут соблюдать простые правила. Надеюсь, эти люди - ваши знакомые которым можно доверять, а не кто-то откуда то левый. Потому как в случае чего - камни прилетят вам, а не им.